# What is the best way to check if data is inside constraints? Linear programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, computational-geometry

Assume that every black line can be displayed on this linear equation. Let's define them as constraints.

$$y = Kx + M$$
where $K$ is the slope and $M$ is the bias.

The purple is my data. My goal is to confirm that the data is inside the constraints. But how can I do that? In this case, it's 12 black lines, that means 13 equations because I'm counting also the open gap also as a line.

Anyway, they are the constraints.
How can I prove with math that the purple data is bounded around these black lines if I know the data and the linear equations?

Should I use a specific method such as linear programming?
Or should I only use if-statements e.g regular programming?

Let's define the constraints.

$$y = K_1 x + M_1$$
$$y = K_2 x + M_2$$
$$y = K_3 x + M_3$$
$$\vdots$$
$$y = K_{13} x + M_{13}$$

[image]

**Update:**

There are actually multiple constraints.

[image]

Comment: As @JohanLofberg noted, your black polygon is not convex.  Was that intended, or can we assume convexity?

Comment: @RobPratt We can assume everything that will work =) I updated my question. Assume that we have unknown data. We check if that data is inside one of these constraints (round circles). If yes = identified.

Answer (score 1):

A general way to do this for $N$ arbitrary polygons in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is to proceed in three steps(note -- definitely not optimized for speed/size):

1. Partition the $N$ polygons $(P_i)_{i\in 1...N}$ into convex components (i.e., Let $P_{ij}$ be the $jth$ component in the [convex partition](https://algorist.com/problems/Polygon_Partitioning.html) of polygon $P_i$).
2. Express each $P_{ij}$ as a system of half-planes $A_{(ij)}\mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}_{(ij)}$ (not strict equalities -- we need to define the interior of each $P_{ij}$). Since the $P_{ij}$ are [convex polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon), [this construction will always exist](http://lavalle.pl/planning/node79.html).
3. For each data point $\mathbf{x}_k \in \mathbb{R^n}$ check it against each system of inequalities $A_{(ij)}\mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}_{(ij)}$, stopping when you find an $P_{ij}$ whose system is satisfied by $\mathbf{x}_k$. If none are satisfied, it is outside of all polygons. If $\mathbf{x}_k$ satisfies system $A_{(pq)}\mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}_{(pq)}$ then it is contained in $P_q$.

That is the basic algo. You could make it a bit more efficient if you sorted the order of the polygons test based on how close $\mathbf{x}_k$ is to the *centroid* of each $P_{ij}$ (closest to furthest). You'd likely need to use a $kd-$tree or something like that to avoid the quadratic explosion of comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to find the convex hull and express each purple point as a convex combination of the resulting vertices.  Explicitly, let $(x_p,y_p)$ be the coordinates of purple point $p$, define nonnegative decision variable $\lambda_i$ for vertex $(\hat{x}_i,\hat{y}_i)$, and solve the linear system
\begin{align}
\sum_i \hat{x}_i \lambda_i &= x_p \\
\sum_i \hat{y}_i \lambda_i &= y_p\\
\sum_i \lambda_i &= 1
\end{align}
This system is feasible if and only if the purple point is within the bounded region.

As a shortcut, you can first find the convex hull of the purple points and check only the vertices in that subset.

Comment: Note that the drawn black figure is not convex, so computing the vertices of that non-convex polyhedra and then checking inclusion in the convex hull of those could fail (not on the data given here, but with a purple point down outside the indent in the bottom the test would give a false positive)

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thanks for mentioning that.  I had missed the nonconvexity of the example figure.

Comment: It's totaly OK! Thank you for the answer. I can solve this problem by using if-statements...but that's sounds very to complex to do. It must be a faster way to check if the data is inside the constraints.